# render option inside renderDT conditional on Input selection in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

When using renderDT with buttons to download the data table, it can be set to download the whole data table, or only the data shown in the current view of the table. I would like to be able to set one way or the other based on the value of one of the input selections by the user.

In the example below, as it is, when clicking on the copy, pdf, or excel buttons, you only get the table in the current view (50 records). If I had render = TRUE in renderDT, then you would download the 200 records for that Type (see example). I would like it to be that when the selection is Type 1, the download would be of only the 50 records in the view, but when Type 2 is selected then it would download all the 200 records for Type 2.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(scales)
library(shinythemes)


# UI -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dataCM <- data.table(variable = 1:400, 
                     type = c(rep('Type 1', 200), rep('Type 2', 200)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  
  dashboardPage(
    
    # Header ================================
    dashboardHeader(
      
      title = span(h3('Shiny App')
      )
    ),
    
    
    # Side bar ==============================
    dashboardSidebar(width = 250,
                  
                     
                     sidebarMenu(id = 'sidebar', 
                                 
                                 # Tabs #
                                 menuItem('Table', tabName = 'tables', icon = icon('bars'))
                                 
                     ),
                     
                     fluidRow(
                       
                       box(width = 12, background = 'black',
                           radioButtons(inputId = 'checksubspecialty',
                                        label = 'Choose Row',
                                        choices = list('Type 1',
                                                       'Type 2')))
                       
                     )
    ),
    
    
    # Body ==================================
    dashboardBody(
      
      tabItems(   

        tabItem(tabName = 'tables',
                fluidRow(
                  box(width = 12,
                      DTOutput('tableSurg')))
        ))
      
      
    )
  )
  
)

# Server --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    
    req(input$checksubspecialty)
      
      dataM <- data.table(dataCM %>% filter(type %in% input$checksubspecialty))
      
      dataM
  
    
  })

  
  output$tableSurg <- renderDT( # adding render = TRUE or FALSE in here is what sets if the download is of all or only the viewed data
    
{
    dt <-  data_subset()

    dt
    
  },
  rownames = FALSE,
  extensions = 'Buttons',
  options = list(
    pageLength = 50, 
    scrollY= '500px',
    scrollX = TRUE,
    dom = 'Bfrtip', 
    columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-left', targets = '_all')),
    buttons = list(
      list(extend = 'copy', title = "Title"), 
      list(extend = 'excel', title = "Title"), 
      list(extend = 'pdf', title = "Title")
    )
  ))
  
}



# Run the application -------------------------------------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Where did you add `render = TRUE`  to download the complete data?

Comment: Just after renderDT, between the ( and {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
# Server --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    
    req(input$checksubspecialty)
    
    dataM <- data.table(dataCM %>% filter(type %in% input$checksubspecialty))
    
    dataM
    
  })
  
  TORF <- reactive({
    if (input$checksubspecialty == "Type 1") TRUE else FALSE
  })
  
  output$tableSurg <- renderDT( server = TORF(), # adding server = TRUE or FALSE in here is what sets if the download is of all or only the viewed data
    
    {
      dt <-  data_subset()
      
      dt
      
    },
    rownames = FALSE,
    extensions = 'Buttons',
    options = list(
      pageLength = 50, 
      scrollY= '500px',
      scrollX = TRUE,
      dom = 'Bfrtip', 
      columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-left', targets = '_all')),
      buttons = list(
        list(extend = 'copy', title = "Title"), 
        list(extend = 'excel', title = "Title"), 
        list(extend = 'pdf', title = "Title")
      )
    ))
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @YBS. It does not work, it does not seem that the server argument in renderDT responds to a reactive value.

Comment: Hm, strange, whether I select Type 1 or Type 2, it only prints 50 records. Do you know why it could be that it does not work for me?

Comment: Perhaps you need to update DT package or restart RStudio.