# How can save or copy all the data.frame in Shiny with a table in renderDT (from package DT)

Tags: r, shiny, download, package, dt

I have a table with more than 100 rows and I want to download it like an excel file (for this exercise I used `iris` data frame), I decided to use the extensions `Buttons` from package `DT` (https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html). However, I have the option to download  the rows that are on the screen.

[image]

Here is the code that I use in the shiny:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Define UI for the data frame in DT
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Test if I can copy or save more than 10 rows"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    fluidPage(
        
        # Show the table
        mainPanel(
          DTOutput('tbl')
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to the data.frame
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$tbl = renderDT(
    iris, extensions = 'Buttons',
    options = list(dom = 'Blfrtip',
                   buttons = c('copy', 'excel')
    )
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My session info is this:

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS 13.2.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] DT_0.27.1   shiny_1.7.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.10       rstudioapi_0.13   magrittr_2.0.3    xtable_1.8-4     
 [5] R6_2.5.1          rlang_1.1.0       fastmap_1.1.1     tools_4.1.2      
 [9] cli_3.6.0         jquerylib_0.1.4   withr_2.5.0       htmltools_0.5.4  
[13] crosstalk_1.2.0   ellipsis_0.3.2    yaml_2.3.7        digest_0.6.31    
[17] lifecycle_1.0.3   later_1.3.0       sass_0.4.5        htmlwidgets_1.6.1
[21] promises_1.2.0.1  rsconnect_0.8.25  memoise_2.0.1     cachem_1.0.7     
[25] mime_0.12         compiler_4.1.2    bslib_0.4.2       jsonlite_1.8.4   
[29] httpuv_1.6.5
```

I would like to download or copy all the table like in the page: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html

[image]

I tried a similar problem in this [render option inside renderDT conditional on Input selection in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177342/render-option-inside-renderdt-conditional-on-input-selection-in-shiny), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe it helps to render the table client-side (`DT::renderDT(..., server = FALSE)`) although this will make tables from large datasets more sluggish.

Comment: Many thanks @I_O, adding `server = FALSE` work it very well....